# Ignore ng-blur event for certain elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events

I have a search field with suggestion box below it. When I type in the search field, the suggestions appear below it. When I click somewhere outside the field, I want the suggestion box to disappear. And I want to be able to click on a suggestion and perform a search.

```
<input ng-blur="suggestionBox.hide()" ng-model='someModel' />

<div class='suggestion-box'>
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="suggestion in suggestions" ng-click="someFunction()">suggestion.name</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The problem is that because of the `ng-blur`, the `ng-click` is not triggered - the suggestion box becomes hidden but the click event doesn't trigger. I tried `ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); someFunction()"` but it doesn't work. I tried to set timeout on the `hide()` method, and it works but I have to set a big timeout like 200ms and generally I think that is a bad solution.

**edit:**
http://plnkr.co/edit/9BR7Sv2502S87HO56Ofp?p=preview

Comment: Is there anyway you could set up a jsbin or fiddle?

Comment: @bencripps here: http://plnkr.co/edit/9BR7Sv2502S87HO56Ofp?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

One thing I've done is provided ng-mousedown and ng-mouseup functions on items i want to click on while circumventing the onBlur. I haven't found any other way around it. In my case it was a sort of a cancel edit button.

1. On mousedown i set a flag "inWhateverMode = true". The mousedown is important because it fires before the blur.
2. In the blur handler, check to see if inWhateverMode.
3. On mouseup you cleanup any flags...complete the intended action.

This is handy when wanting to allow the user to click on a button, then move the cursor off the initial button, and then let go without negative impacts. Like inadvertently clicking a delete button.

Updated Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/raJzMor9ci8dLgzXuQII?p=preview

```
ng-mousedown='startToShowItem(item)' ng-mouseup='show(item)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I think this is what you're looking for:

http://plnkr.co/edit/r3SlOXg6VuTZDABPCAxq?p=preview

The function runs, and then the drop down disappears?

> $scope.show = function(item) {
>       $scope.hidden = true;
>       alert(item)
>     };

modified HTML:

```
<input ng-model='search' />
<div ng-hide='hidden' style='border:1px solid black'>
```

Comment: No, the box should disappear when you click anywhere outside the input field.

Comment: So it works right, except that the box doesnt disappear when you click outside the element?

Comment: Yes, I don't think you understand the problem. I want to hide the box when you click ANYWHERE outside the input field. That works great with the ng-blur attribute, but since I have ng-click on li elements, the box disappears before the ng-click event is triggered.